# How to process creditcard payment option on your website (without redirect to paypal) paypalexpressceckout with ci-merchant library

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, codeigniter-2, ci-merchant

I am using ci-merchant library and integrated it succesfully and also works for paypal account owner user.But dont know how to processs for user who dont have paypal acc and wants to pay via credit or debit card on my website only**(without redirect to paypal)** any idea????abt that.....this is the code i use for the normal paypal payment in my controller and works good as well..

```
    $this->load->library('merchant');
    $this->merchant->load('paypal_express');
    $settings = $this->merchant->default_settings();
        $settings = array(
        'username' => 'takeout_api1.rest.com',
        'password' => '1369227981',
        'signature' => 'AnOQDpMvzNQqHN5u7vb9BKLaKYLoALq6R0g3ohOwD4RQgO0DQDI5l7V4',
        'test_mode' => true,
        );


    $this->merchant->initialize($settings);
    $params = array(
        'amount' => 1500.00,
        'currency' => 'CAD',
        'return_url' => 'http://192.168.1.7/takeout/order_detail/test',
        'cancel_url' => 'http://192.168.1.7/takeout/order_detail/test');

        $response = $this->merchant->purchase($params);

function test()
    {

    $settings = array(
    'username' => 'takeout_api1.rest.com',
    'password' => '1369227981',
    'signature' => 'AnOQDpMvzNQqHN5u7vb9BKLaKYLoALq6R0g3ohOwD4RQgO0DQDI5l7V4',
    'test_mode' => true);
$this->merchant->initialize($settings);

$params = array(
    'amount' => 1500.00,
    'currency' => 'CAD',
    'return_url' => 'http://192.168.1.7/takeout/order_detail/test',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://192.168.1.7/takeout/order_detail/test');
    $response = $this->merchant->purchase_return($params);
    if ($response->success())
{
    // mark order as complete
    echo "yo";
    exit;
}
else
{
    $message = $response->message();
    echo('Error processing payment: ' . $message);
    exit;
}


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### You could interface your Merchant services

```
interface merchantServiceInterface
{
    public function initialize();

    public function purchase();

    public function purchase_return();
}
```

### Paypal

```
class Paypal implements merchantServiceInterface
{
    public function initialize(){}

    public function purchase(){}

    public function purchase_return(){}
}
```

### Credit/Debit Cards

```
class Realex implements merchantServiceInterface
{
    public function initialize(){}

    public function purchase(){}

    public function purchase_return(){}
}
```

Now in your form, have a little radio button group and ask the user to select
either paypal or credit/debit card

```
<label>Choose a payment Method</label>

<label>Paypal<label>
<input type="radio" name="merchant" value="paypal" />

<label>Credit/Debit Card<label>
<input type="radio" name="merchant" value="debit" />
```

### Merchant Library

```
class Merchant
{
    protected $_service;

    public function __construct(merchantServiceInterface $service)
    {
        $this->_service = $service;
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        // Will either run Paypal/Realex initialize()
        // Depending on what instance was passed to _service
        //
        $this->_service->initialize();
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function method()
    {
        if($this->input->post('merchant') == 'paypal')
        {
            $service = new Paypal();
        }

        elseif($this->input->post('merchant') == 'debit')
        {
            $service = new Realex();
        }

        $this->load->library('Merchant', $service);
        $this->merchant->initialize();
    }
}
```

## Edit to answer your comment

**I just used Realex as an example**

You need to figure out what both libraries have in common, or at a very low level abstraction figure out what they share.

an example would be

- They **both** need a initialize method to configure options
- They **both** need to send a request to an API
- They **both** need a responce
- etc etc keep abstracting away

How you handle these, will be unique to the library itself.

```
interface merchantServiceInterface
{
    // Use the facade design pattern here
    // so configuration is done in each library
    public function initialize();

    // Send a request with data 
    // Paypal - use http_build_query and curl
    // Realex - use xml and curl
    public function request(array $data);

    public function responce();
}
```

Comment: hi philip..i got you completely....and this flow that you have posted i already know this flow....I just need to know what shuld be the content in intialize,purchaseand purchase_return method for credit/debit card(in relax class)....Ofcourse that cant be the same as my method of paypal

Answer (score 0):

*Paypal Express Checkout* doesn't support taking credit cards on your site. It is an off-site gateway, so redirect is mandatory.

You need to explore using PayPal Pro, Payflow, or any number of other gateways which support accepting credit cards directly on your website (plus the extra PCI requirements which come with that).

Comment: according to this link they said it supports... https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_additional-payment-ref-impl1 but i am not able to find anythibng related it neither in ci-merchant lib nor in api

Comment: That flow chart is misleading, I can only assume they meant "how paypal could be added to your existing website which already accepts credit cards". Paypal Express is hosted-only. Your customers don't have to have a paypal account, but they do have to enter their card details on paypal's website, not yours.

Comment: OKay...thanks for your valuable comments....i will check it and get back to you coz i have also seen the video in which they have mentioned thta you can do it on your own website...Otherwise i have to move on paypalPro...Thanks again for your feedback and help